# Data attribute change not being observed

Tags: angularjs

I'm changing data attribute of a dom element and using $observe within the directive to detect for any changes but it doesn't seem to work after clicking on the "change data" button

HTML

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div id="container" data-name="somename" mydirective>Data</div>
    <button ng-click="changeData();">Change Data Attribute</button>
</body>
```

JS

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.changeData = function() {
    var el = document.querySelector('#container');
    angular.element(el).attr('data-name', 'hello');
  }
});

app.directive('mydirective', function() {
  return {
     link : function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
       attrs.$observe("name", function (newValue) {
           console.log(newValue);
       });
  }
}
```

Plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/saM7fO0DdsaaDBW7ADQH?p=preview

Comment: thats a non-angular way of managing attrs... for angularjs way do it as suggested by MiG

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use expression `data-name="{{datax}}"` ?

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.datax = "somename";

$scope.changeData = function() {
 //var el = document.querySelector('#container');
 //angular.element(el).attr('data-name', 'hello');
 $scope.datax = "hello";
}
});

app.directive('mydirective', function() {
return {
  link : function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
   attrs.$observe("name", function (newValue) {
        console.log(newValue);

   });
  }
}
});
```

Comment: If the element who's data I want to change is not in scope then $scope.datax won't work and I have to rely on attr('data-name')